# is it possible to have a jquery tab container inside a dojo dialog?

Tags: jquery, dojo

I am trying to build a jquery tab container inside a dojo dialog. Various attemps have rendered nothing but failure. Can it be done? could you suggest a way to do it?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should definitely be possible. Here is a fiddle of it working:
https://jsfiddle.net/r1mj9v72/2/

And the relevant part that makes it fit in a dialog is this:

```
var dialog = new DijitDialog({
   title: 'Tab Dialog',
   content: tabContainer
});
```

More importantly, what have you tried that isn't working? That answer might be better in terms of helping you with your experience with dojo.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. Correct me if i am wrong, but i see a dojo tab container inside a dojo Dialog. What i  am trying to accomplish is a jquery tab container     

$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });

inside a dojo dialog. thank you very much

Comment: Hi Prefijo, you are right. Sorry I misread your initial request. I've updated the fiddle to show it with a dojo tab container.